# C-statistic (or AUC) for fractional logistic regression (i.e. continuous regression)

Tags: logistic, goodness-of-fit, roc, auc, concordance

I have proportional data to which I have fit a logistic regression (i.e. fractional logistic regression). The statistician in our group wants me to provide a c-statistic for the regression.

My understanding was that the c-statistic was equivalent to the AUC, which evaluates the performance of the model for binary classification. Because my response variable is proportional, there is no "true positive" or "false positive" and thus most of the methods for calculating the AUC don't appear valid (e.g. using `pROC` or `ROCR` libraries) as these require as inputs a vector of "true positives"/class labels and our vector of predicted probabilities.

However, I also understand that the concordance statistic (c-statistic) can be calculated as:

> The probability that a randomly selected subject who experienced the
> outcome will have a higher predicted probability of having the outcome
> occur compared to a randomly selected subject who did not experience
> the event. One can calculate the c-statistic by taking all possible
> pairs of subjects consisting of one subject who experienced the event
> of interest and one subject who did not experience the event of
> interest. The c-statistic is the proportion of such pairs in which the
> subject who experienced the event had a higher predicted probability
> of experiencing the event than the subject who did not experience the
> event.

From: [Interpreting the concordance statistic of a logistic regression model: relation to the variance and odds ratio of a continuous explanatory variable](https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2288-12-82) by Peter C Austin and Ewout W Steyerberg.

Could this be extended to the continuous setting where we look at pairs of observations and compare the concordance of the ordering of their proportions with the ordering of their predicted probabilities? Notably, is there a function in R which does this? Or literature which I could cite to support this approach for reviewers?

Comment: Do you want the c-index or a full ROC curve?

Comment: Just the index.